# Can't use paste to get the real object inside a function

Tags: r, object, paste

```
x = rnorm(20,0,1)
y = rnorm(20,0,2)
df = cbind(data.frame(x=x,y=y))
reg_1 = lm(y ~ x, data=df)
summary(reg_1) #this is my goal but need to use a different approach.
```

The following code does not work:

```
i=1
j = paste("reg_",i,sep="")
g = summary(j) #it was expected "g" to be the reg_1 model summary
```

I guess it does not work because the "j" object is a string. Tks.

Comment: you can use `summary(get(j))`, but you are better off organizing your work differently, i.e. by using lists rather than sequentially named variables ...

Comment: FYI, this (both the usage of `get()` and the suggestion to instead use a list) is covered by [R FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Promoted from a comment to an answer.)

You can use `summary(get(j))`, but you are better off organizing your work differently, i.e. by using lists rather than sequentially named variables ... as @JoshO'Brien points out, this is covered by [R FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).